# Second-to-last vs second-to-previous

Tags: word-choice

From my understanding, when given a sequence of items, [second-to-last](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second-to-last) designates the item preceding the penultimate item on the sequence. Example:

[image]

If we consider one item of the sequence as the current one, what adjective would we use to designate the item preceding the previous item in the sequence? Is "second-to-previous" the correct adjective to use in this situation? Example:

[image]

Comment: The link you provided defines second-to-last as "penultimate, next to last, immediately preceding the end of a sequence or list" - that certainly doesn't apply to the first dog you've highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Second to last is the penultimate item. First to last is the first counting from the "last" direction. Second to last is the second object from that direction. (Then again, this is rarely used, and it could be that a given group of English speakers might use second to last as either penultimate or pen-penultimate.)

Also, the way I see that picture, they look like they're passing me in the direction of the arrow, so I'd actually call the farthest to the left the last one, and the next second-to-last.

Next is the opposite of last when you're in the middle of the list, and you use them as directions. Talking about the one who just passed, you call it the last one (as in last to pass), and the one after that as second to last, or next to last. To keep moving down the list, you could say "the one before that." (I've never heard third to last, but after a moment to figure it out, it would make sense.)

In the other direction is the next object, which is about to pass you. you could keep moving in that direction either by simply saying "the one after that" or maybe by saying second to come. (or third or so on)

Basically, in the middle of the list, you treat it as two different lists, the ones that have already come, and the ones who are soon to come.

Please let me know if I need to clarify something.

Answer (score 2):

Using *previous* does not seem natural in this case (it has more of an implication of time passing). But perhaps in context. I would go with:

> The second dog before the current one.

or

> Two dogs before the current one.

although this one might refer to both dogs before the current one.

Answer (score 2):

We normally have the idea "current item in a list" only when we are *iterating* the list.

If you wish to iterate a list of items and, while doing so, refer back to a previous item in relation to the current item, you could use the word **back**.

**Unlike the dog *two dogs back*, by this age the dog should have had its rabies shots.**

The name of the item contained in the list becomes the name of the iterator and is cast in the singular or the plural:

two *dogs* back

one *dog* back

You could also say "unlike the last dog" which, in the context of iterating the list, would mean "the *previous* dog" not the final dog.

You could even use the word **ago**:

Unlike the dog two dogs ago...

These words (back, ago) are deictic:  they reveal the speaker's orientation in relation to the act of iterating the list and thus when *stationed* on a particular item in the list.

Ordinal adjectives refer to the position of the item relative to the beginning of the list, or relative to the *tail-end* of the list, not relative to the current item.

Answer (score 1):

To me you have LAST, then next to last, THEN second to last. Otherwise "second" and "next" are used without reference to their meaning.

Granted, we use "first, second..." at the head of a list. But it makes no sense at all to call the penultimate item the "SECOND to last," because that makes the last item the "FIRST to last," which is pure nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the dictionary meaning of the word "penultimate", and one of the definitions was: "next to last" or "second to last", therefore, the words "next to" and "second to" are synonymous. As in the expression, "I second that emotion", which means you also stand right by or right with that emotion, but secondly you do this, right after this emotion, there is the penultimate. It matters less from which direction the last thing is considered to be... the penultimate is simply second and always next to the last thing, whichever place, or wherever this last thing is considered to be.

Comment: Note: In the picture of dogs in the first post, the last dogs are the ones at either of the ends of the line of dogs, so the penultimate dog could or would be the dog directly in front of or behind whichever dog is considered to be last. So, we first determine which one of the two dogs is last, either one or the other on each end of the line-up, and then the penultimate would be the dog exactly next to it.

Comment: "I second that emotion" is actually a play on parliamentary procedure, where a motion must be seconded before it is considered for discussion or voting. It has nothing to do with standing next to an emotion.

Comment: Just using metaphorical language to give a sense of what I am trying to explain. This quote/saying was not used to prove or implicitly explain my answer. I think you are nit-picking here, but that's fine, I don't have to offer any help here, just let me know and I'll delete my account or back off a bit. How is your morning going? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Penultimate and <strike>ante</strike>preprior.

---

The second to last item: penult (noun form of penultimate).

Item preceding the previous: <strike>ante</strike>preprior.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'Anteprior' doesn't have any hits searching online, which implies it is extremely rare or non-existent. Did you make up this word, or did you find this word? If the latter, where?

Comment: I made it up. <: )

We could also go with preprior. That leaves space for antepreprior denoting the item preceding the preprior.